# How to convert Jupyter notebook to PDF via Latex?

Tags: pdf, jupyter-notebook, latex, nbconvert

I am trying to convert a Jupyter notebook to pdf via Latex using ***nbconvert***, in order to automatically include citations to articles contained in a separate .bib file. I worked according to the tutorial/example [here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jupyter/nbconvert-examples/blob/master/citations/Tutorial.ipynb). Such a tutorial was suggested in the nbconvert documentation, [here](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/latex_citations.html).

I have the following files in the same directory in which I am running the Jupyter notebook:

- citations.tplx (the template to be used to include the bibliography)
- references.bib (a .bib file containing the citations, taken from Google Scholar)

Inside the markdown cells, I use the following syntax to cite a work:

`<cite data-cite="cortez2009modeling">(Cortez, 2009)</cite>`

where such a work in the .bib file is reported as follows:

```
@article{cortez2009modeling,
  title={Modeling wine preferences by data mining from physicochemical properties},
  author={Cortez, Paulo and Cerdeira, Ant{\'o}nio and Almeida, Fernando and Matos, Telmo and Reis, Jos{\'e}},
  journal={Decision support systems},
  volume={47},
  number={4},
  pages={547--553},
  year={2009},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

In a new notebook, also saved in the same location, I run the following command, also taken by the tutorial mentioned above:

```
%%bash
jupyter nbconvert --to latex --template citations.tplx --post pdf my_notebook.ipynb
```

I get a very long output, full of warnings, but basically, the error is:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdf'`

I also tried to do this according to other tutorials on the web, but even when the PDF file was indeed generated (using a slightly different nbconvert command), my citations were not captured in the text (a question mark would appear instead), and there was no bibliography at the end of the document. A warning would say there were 'problems' with Bibtex, but nothing more.

In the following, I report the complete output of the command I wrote above:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-nbconvert", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 254, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 844, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 290, in initialize
    super().initialize(argv)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 225, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 713, in parse_command_line
    self.update_config(self.cli_config)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py", line 220, in update_config
    self._load_config(config)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py", line 190, in _load_config
    warn(msg)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 120, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 1214, in hold_trait_notifications
    self.notify_change(change)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 1227, in notify_change
    return self._notify_observers(change)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 1264, in _notify_observers
    c(event)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 265, in _postprocessor_class_changed
    self.postprocessor_factory = import_item(new)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/utils/importstring.py", line 38, in import_item
    return __import__(parts[0])
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdf'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-c5829f9d50d0> in <module>
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('bash', '', 'jupyter nbconvert --to latex --template citations.tplx --post pdf Orlando_Taddeo_CW.ipynb\n')

/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2397             with self.builtin_trap:
   2398                 args = (magic_arg_s, cell)
-> 2399                 result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2400             return result
   2401 

/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/script.py in named_script_magic(line, cell)
    140             else:
    141                 line = script
--> 142             return self.shebang(line, cell)
    143 
    144         # write a basic docstring:

/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/decorator.py in fun(*args, **kw)
    230             if not kwsyntax:
    231                 args, kw = fix(args, kw, sig)
--> 232             return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
    233     fun.__name__ = func.__name__
    234     fun.__doc__ = func.__doc__

/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    186     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    188 
    189         if callable(arg):

/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/script.py in shebang(self, line, cell)
    243             sys.stderr.flush()
    244         if args.raise_error and p.returncode!=0:
--> 245             raise CalledProcessError(p.returncode, cell, output=out, stderr=err)
    246 
    247     def _run_script(self, p, cell, to_close):

CalledProcessError: Command 'b'jupyter nbconvert --to latex --template citations.tplx --post pdf Orlando_Taddeo_CW.ipynb\n'' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Could anyone please shed some light on this? I really can't figure out why it does not work.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: One more info: I have ***pandoc*** 2.12 installed

Comment: Have you installed PyPDF2? `pip install PyPDF2`

Comment: @TCArlen thank you, byt PyPDF2 seems not to be able to handle Latex. Also, another of the issues I have is that the Latex intermediate file that is generated when I use the alternative approaches does not include the bibliography. So, there must be some issue in this step as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is rather late, but if you still need a solution (and for anyone else who does): you can use the template solution, but your working directory needs to look like this:

```
Project
|-- source.ipynb
|-- references.bib
|-- templates
   |-- my_template
      |-- index.tex.j2
      |-- latex
         |-- base.tex.j2
         |-- conf.json
         |-- display_priority.j2
         |-- document_contents.tex.j2
         |-- index.tex.j2
         |-- null.j2
         |-- report.tex.j2
         |-- style_bw_ipython.tex.j2
         |-- style_bw_python.tex.j2
         |-- style_ipython.tex.j2
         |-- style_jupyter.tex.j2
         |-- style_python.tex.j2
```

where the directory `latex` was copied from the base templates directories installed with TeX. You will also need to manually change a few lines in each `.j2` file - replace

```
((* extends other_template.j2 *))
```

with

```
((* extends latex/other_template.j2 *))
```

to ensure that `nbconvert` understands your directory structure. You will only need to do this a few times - just follow the `extends` tree, starting at `index.tex.j2` and ending at `null.j2`.

Finally, run

```
jupyter nbconvert --to pdf --template=templates/my_template "source.ipynb"
```

to compile `source.ipynb` into `source.pdf`.

Hope this helps!